# How to extend/expand array of objects based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, expand

I am trying to convert

**Source:**

```
[{
  dayIds: [1],
  timeRanges: [{
  end: 1200,
  start: 800
}],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
}, {
  dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
  timeRanges: [{
  end: 720,
  start: 360
}, {
  end: 230,
  start: 160
}],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
}]
```

**Expected:**

```
[{
  dayIds: [1],
  endTime: 1200,
  startTime: 800,
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
  endTime: 720,
  startTime: 360
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"

}, {
  dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
  endTime: 230,
  startTime: 160,
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
```

I have a hard time converting above source array into the expected flat array where for each timeRange object the new object has to be constructed.

Any suggestions to improve in array operations and also to solve the above problem.

This is what I have tried until now.

```js
let array = [{
  dayIds: [1],
  timeRanges: [{
  end: 1200,
  start: 800
}],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
}, {
  dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
  timeRanges: [{
  end: 720,
  start: 360
}, {
  end: 230,
  start: 160
}, {
  end: 230,
  start: 160
}],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
}]
var expected = [];
array.forEach(a=>{
a.timeRanges.forEach((tr,index)=>{
expected.push({days:a.dayIds,startTime:tr.start,endTime:tr.end,timezone_type:a.timezoneType[index].timezone_type});
});
});

console.log(expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let arr = [{
  dayIds: [1],
  timeRanges: [{
      end: 1200,
      start: 800
    }],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
    }]
}

, {
  dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
  timeRanges: [{
  end: 720,
  start: 360
}, {
  end: 230,
  start: 160
}],
  timezoneType: [{
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}, {
  timezone_type: "AM/PM"
}]
}]


arr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return [...acc, ...cur.timeRanges.map(timeRange => {
        return {dayIds:cur.dayIds, timezone_type:cur.timezoneType[0].timezone_type, endTime:timeRange.end, startTime:timeRange.start}
    })] 
}, [])

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap` and destructuring.

```js
const convert = (arr) =>
  arr.flatMap(({ dayIds, timeRanges, timezoneType: [{ timezone_type }] }) =>
    timeRanges.map((range) => ({ ...range, dayIds: [...dayIds], timezone_type }))
  );
const data = [
  {
    dayIds: [1],
    timeRanges: [
      {
        end: 1200,
        start: 800,
      },
    ],
    timezoneType: [
      {
        timezone_type: "AM/PM",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    dayIds: [1, 2, 3],
    timeRanges: [
      {
        end: 720,
        start: 360,
      },
      {
        end: 230,
        start: 160,
      },
    ],
    timezoneType: [
      {
        timezone_type: "AM/PM",
      },
      {
        timezone_type: "AM/PM",
      },
      {
        timezone_type: "AM/PM",
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(convert(data))
```